# Jquery next() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
<div class="window-compl">
    <div class="window showincatalog showing">
    <h2>Text1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="window">
    <h2>Text2</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="window showincatalog">
    <h2>Text3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="window showincatalog">
    <h2>Text4</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use jquery selectors next() and prev() in this function:

```
function rotate(direction) {    
    var current = $('.showing');
    if (direction==0)
        var next = $('.showing').prev('.showincatalog');
    else
        var next = $('.showing').next('.showincatalog');
}
```

It works when all div tags have class showincatalog, but stops, when one of them not.

Would be great if someone knows why this is not working

update: I need select div with class "showincatalog" and Text3, but $('.showing').next('.showincatalog') return nothing.

Comment: It works exactly as advertised, no? I think you need to use .find() instead

Comment: `$('.showing)` should be `$('.showing')`  missing single-quote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
function rotate(direction) {
    var current = $('.showing'),
        next;
    if (direction == 0) {
        next = $('.showing').prevAll('.showincatalog').first();
    } else {
        next = $('.showing').nextAll('.showincatalog').first();
    }
    current.removeClass('showing');
    next.addClass('showing');
}
```

[See example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AsfzP/)

Answer (score 3):

I think I get what you're trying to do, and have been stung by this myself. The trick is that `next` either gets the next element or gets nothing. If you want "the next element that matches this selector," use `.nextAll('selector').first()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're specifying in code that you want the next element that has the class `showincatalog`. If you want to include the divs that don't...remove the selector from the `prev()` and `next()` calls.

...I'm assuming that's what you mean by broken. If the behavior is different then you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the JQuery documentation on [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

> The method optionally accepts a
>   selector expression of the same type
>   that we can pass to the $() function.
>   **If the immediately following sibling
>   matches the selector**, it remains in
>   the newly constructed jQuery object;
>   **otherwise, it is excluded**.